# delete all numbers greater than a particular value

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to do an algorithm to delete all numbers from a queue greater than a particular value, here is my code.

```
void problem(Queue* c, int x) {
    if (isEmpty(c)) {
        printf("empty queue");       
    } else {
        Node* n1 = c->top; 
        Node* n2 = c->top->next;
        while (n2 != NULL) {
            if (n2->value > x) {
                Nodo* aux = n2;
                n1->next = aux->next;
                aux->next = NULL;
                free(aux);
            }
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = n2->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when the `if` condition is true. In that case you don't want to continue after that `if` block with `n1 = n2;`, because `n2` is now a reference to the deleted node. On the other hand, you still need to move `n2` to point to the next node, so that should happen in the `if` block *before* the current node is freed.

So do:

```
void problem(Queue* c, int x) {
    if (isEmpty(c)) {
        printf("empty queue");       
    } else {
        Node* n1 = c->top; 
        Node* n2 = c->top->next;
        while (n2 != NULL) {
            if (n2->value > x) {
                Node* aux = n2;
                n2 = n2->next; // <-- add this; n1 remains unchanged.
                n1->next = n2; // <-- now this can be shorter code
                free(aux);
            } else { // Make conditional
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n2->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`aux->next = NULL;` is not wrong, but not needed either, since this node is freed.

Comment: Additionally, line `aux->next = NULL;` is redundant since `aux` is going to be freed anyway.

Comment: Absolutely, @Stef. Updated.